# (C++) reverse_iterator couldn't be dereferenced

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator

I have an iterator and reverse_iterator for my own class, that looks like that:

```
template<typename T>
class OwnClass {
    ...
    class iterator :
            public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {
       ...
       const T& operator*() const {...}
       const T*& operator->() const {...}
    };

    class reverse_iterator :
            public std::reverse_iterator<iterator> {
    public:
        using std::reverse_iterator<iterator>::reverse_iterator;
    };
};
```

So, there is a problem: reverse_iterator couldn't be dereferenced:

```
OwnClass<int> k;
std::cerr << *(k.begin()) << std::endl; // ok
std::cerr << *(k.rbegin()) << std::endl; // error
```

Compiler says that problem is here:

```
../iterator:650:64: error: binding value of type 'const int' to reference to type 'int' drops 'const' qualifier
reference operator*() const {_Iter __tmp = current; return *--__tmp;}
                                                           ^~~~~~~~
```

I think this is because I use reverse_iterator adaptor not in right way. So, what me to do?

(it's not good to make reverse_iterator a class, where I rewrite all the iterator's methods, this is why I need inheritance from std::reverse_iterator::reverse_iterator)

Comment: You may find this helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847789/reverse-iterator-adapter

Comment: you may just write "using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>" instead of inheriting... regarding the error, provide an [mcve], please

Comment: One suggestion (even if it's not really related to the question), if you have an undelying container (let's say, an `std::vector`), you could just do `typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;` and just use the iterator of the vector as the iterator of your class.

Comment: BTW, why does your (non-const) iterator operator* return a *const* reference ? this is likely the problem ...